# Как Роскомнадзор собирается технически блокировать Telegram?

Tags: telegram, socks5

Они забанят весь Google Play и App Store или будут банить IP всех серверов с которыми будет соединяться приложение?

Comment: Так же как и youtube, vk и википедию.

Comment: Не уверен, что вопрос для ruSO...

Comment: @Hipster ........... ты нашёл статью какого-то хейтера и решил что это какой-то аргумент?.........[Такие статьи выходят чуть ли не каждый год, после первой-второй годовщины SO. С тех пор так и закатывается](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4770/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82-stack-overflow#comment17012_4770)

Comment: @Hipster вопрос заката SO лучше обсуждать в [чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--) или на мете. Возможно обсуждение приведет к каким-то действиям по улучшению ситуации. Главное конкретно описать ту проблему которую вы видите.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

РНК сам никого блочить не будет. Все, что он сделает - добавит запись в реестр запрещенных сайтов. После этого каждый Российский оператор связи начнет блокировать так, как у него это организовано. Единого стандарта для блокировок не существует. Обычно используется один или несколько следующих методов:

- Подмена ответов DNS - если приложение использует доменное имя при поиске своих серверов оно их не найдет.
- Блокирование IP адресов перечисленных в реестре запрещенных сайтов
- Блокирование IP описанных в DNS записях домена
- Фильтрация HTTP трафика, подмена ответов на запросы на запрещенные URL
- Фильтрация HTTPS трафика по имени домена в пакетах SSL-рукопожатия (не зашифрованных)

Кроме того возможна фильтрация всего трафика с помощью DPI, который запросто выловит обращения к ресурсу через Socks5, если трафик до самого Socks сервера не зашифрован. Применяется ли по факту кем то данный метод мне не известно.

Кроме того РКН обратится к Apple и Google, после чего те возможно удалят Telegram из магазинов.

Comment: Скорее из РФ запретят скачивание